# Custom form, input with ajax autocomplete not working

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have developed a module with a custom form but I don't know why ajax autocomplete doesn't work. The form works good, but in one of the input field I'd like to have a autocomplete function. The next is part of my code:

`src\Form\Mycustomform.php`

```
...
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $parameter = NULL) {
...
    $form['customer'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Customer'),
      '#id' => 'inpCustomer',
      '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'mymodule.autocomplete',
    );
....
```

`mymodule.routing.yml`

```
mymodule:
  path: 'mycustompath'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\Mycustomform'
    _title: 'Records'
  requirements:
    _permission: mycustompermission

mymodule.autocomplete:
  path: 'autocomplete'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::autocomplete'
    _format: json
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

`\src\Controller\MyModuleController.php`

```
...
class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {

    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {
        $string = $request->query->get('q');
        $matches = array();
        \Drupal:logger('autocomplete')->notice($string);
        $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
        $query->condition('type','customers');
        $query->condition('title', '%'.$string.'%', 'like');
        $query->sort('title');
        $query->range(0,20);
        $entity = $query->execute();
        $nodos = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($entity);
        foreach ($nodos as $row) {
            $matches[] = array('value' => $row->getTitle(), 'label' => $row->getTitle());
        }

        return new JsonResponse($matches);
    }
}
```

If I see drupal log, I never get a register as expected. But if I see conosole log, I don't see ajax request. How could I find where is the problem? I think there isn't an ajax call when I write some letters on the input field. I don't see the circle on the right of the input that is shown when autocomplete is working.

Comment: Can you try without the _format: json? Btw, I think you could still use entity_autocomplete for this, in combination with a custom selection plugin. You just need that plugin then where you override/customize the query. Using #type entity_autocomplete gives you a bunch of additional things like proper handling of default value/validation to make sure your users can really only select a valid node there.. just having the autocomplete means you still need to parse the string, validate it and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found the problem. The code is right. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests I have found the problem. My code is right and it works good. The problem was the template file `input--textfield.html.twig`. Input textfield needs some automplete classes to work and this template deleted them to add some other classes. The required classes are: `form-autocomplete form-text ui-autocomplete-input`. I have changed this template file to add a new class I need but without deleting the other, and then, autocomplete works.

Answer (score 0):

I do not tested your code but I see that your custom form doing completely the same like entity_autocomplete form element https://www.drupal.org/node/2418529

```
$form['customer'] = array(
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#title' => t('Customer'),
      '#id' => 'inpCustomer',
      '#target_type' => 'node',
      '#selection_settings' => array(
        'target_bundles' => array('customers'),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The autocomplete function I have shown is an extract. It is more complex to filter only some customers with some conditions, but thouse code is not important for my question.